# MATLAB: combining and normalizing histograms with different sample sizes

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution, normalize, bins

I have four sets of data, the distribution of which I would like to represent in MATLAB in one figure. Current code is:

```
[n1,x1]=hist([dataset1{:}]);
[n2,x2]=hist([dataset2{:}]);
[n3,x3]=hist([dataset3{:}]);
[n4,x4]=hist([dataset4{:}]);
bar(x1,n1,'hist'); 
hold on; h1=bar(x1,n1,'hist'); set(h1,'facecolor','g')
hold on; h2=bar(x2,n2,'hist'); set(h2,'facecolor','g')
hold on; h3=bar(x3,n3,'hist'); set(h3,'facecolor','g')
hold on; h4=bar(x4,n4,'hist'); set(h4,'facecolor','g')
hold off
```

My issue is that I have different sampling sizes for each group, dataset1 has an n of 69, dataset2 has an n of 23, dataset3 and dataset4 have n's of 10. So how do I normalize the distributions when representing these three groups together?

Is there some way to..for example..divide the instances in each bin by the sampling for that group?

Comment: Why not bar `n1/sum(n1)` instead? Otherwise, maybe  `histogram(x,'Normalization','probability')` would be an alternative.

Comment: The n1/sum(n1) worked great, is there a way to do this with histfit? or some better/easier way to add fit lines?

Answer (score 2):

You can normalize your histograms by dividing by the total number of elements:

```
[n1,x1] = histcounts(randn(69,1));
[n2,x2] = histcounts(randn(23,1));
[n3,x3] = histcounts(randn(10,1));
[n4,x4] = histcounts(randn(10,1));
hold on
bar(x4(1:end-1),n4./sum(n4),'histc');
bar(x3(1:end-1),n3./sum(n3),'histc');
bar(x2(1:end-1),n2./sum(n2),'histc');
bar(x1(1:end-1),n1./sum(n1),'histc');
hold off 
ax = gca;
set(ax.Children,{'FaceColor'},mat2cell(lines(4),ones(4,1),3))
set(ax.Children,{'FaceAlpha'},repmat({0.7},4,1))
```

However, as you can see above, you can do some more things to make your code more simple and short:

1. You only need to `hold on` once.
2. Instead of collecting all the `bar` handles, use the `axes` handle.
3. Plot the bar in ascending order of the number of elements in the dataset, so all histograms will be clearly visible.
4. With the `axes` handle set all properties at one command.

and as a side note - it's better to use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html).

Here is the result:

[image: only hist]

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to also plot the pdf line from `histfit`, then you can save it first, and then plot it normalized:

```
dataset = {randn(69,1),randn(23,1),randn(10,1),randn(10,1)};
fits = zeros(100,2,numel(dataset));
hold on
for k = numel(dataset):-1:1
    total = numel(dataset{k}); % for normalizing
    f = histfit(dataset{k}); % draw the histogram and fit
    % collect the curve data and normalize it:
    fits(:,:,k) = [f(2).XData; f(2).YData./total].';
    x = f(1).XData; % collect the bar positions
    n = f(1).YData; % collect the bar counts
    f.delete % delete the histogram and the fit
    bar(x,n./total,'histc'); % plot the bar
end
ax = gca; % get the axis handle
% set all color and transparency for the bars:
set(ax.Children,{'FaceColor'},mat2cell(lines(4),ones(4,1),3))
set(ax.Children,{'FaceAlpha'},repmat({0.7},4,1))
% plot all the curves:
plot(squeeze(fits(:,1,:)),squeeze(fits(:,2,:)),'LineWidth',3)
hold off
```

Again, there are some other improvements you can introduce to your code:

1. Put everything in a loop to make thigs more easily changed later.
2. Collect all the curves data to one variable so you can plot them all together very easily.

The new result is:

[image: hist & fit]